# Need clearance on instance variable scope in Rails and MVC architecture in general

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I need some clearance on scope of instance variables in rails application (not sure if other frameworks have the similar paradigm)

Lets say I have an instance variable

```
@page_count = some_value
```

inside a controller's index action

So, regarding accessibility of this variable. It should be accessible within its view and I guess from model as well.(right?)

Now, if i call some other action(through other request) say, export in the same controller, the variable @page_count wont have its value which was set inside index action

(***instance variable would not retain its value between different requests, right?***)

Currently to deal with this I am using session scoped variable,

```
session[page_count] = some_value # inside index action
```

Now the variable will be available inside other actions, including the export action ( through other request)

Is this is good approach? using sessions? or there are better alternatives for storing values between different requests?

Suggestions/Comments/pointers, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on what you set `@page_count` to.

If it's like the number of rows in a db table 'pages', and you set it like,

```
@page_count = Page.all.count
```

Then you could use a `before_filter` and set the value there for every controller action you need it. Here's some more info on [filters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters).

Otherwise, if the value of @page_count is something calculated and changes per action, then I think you just have to define it in every action.

Comment: @page_count is calculated using some custom query. and its doesnot change per action. infact i want it to retain its value between different actions called through different requests.

Comment: but if you called the query from another action, would it return a different/incorrect value?

Comment: currently returns a different value(different from what is needed). i want to retain the same value between requests

Comment: then, yeah, if it's not a critical piece of info, i think using sessions hash is ok. I've seen it used that way for storing url's for forwarding and such.

Comment: alright. thnx. though i will wait for some other comments, suggestions. may be there are other alternatives.

Comment: Use `@page_count = Page.count` instead of `@page_count = Page.all.count`. There is huge performance difference between both.

Answer (score 0):

I am not much of experience person but what if you create it as global variable once you set the value of global variable then you can access it in same controller with different methods. I know it is not good practice to use global variable but I hope It solve your problem.

Comment: urjit, thnx for your answer. but for this particular question i am looking for best practices and not just solution.